# Is there any dictionary datatype in android?

Tags: java, android

As i have experience in iOS and newbie to Android development, i wqant to implement grouped tableview in Android.

Can anyone tell me what is the replacement of NSDictionary in android...

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps you should add a picture or something.

Comment: A [HashMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html) is an acceptable replacement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NSDictionary` is just a dictionary type; in Java these are called "Maps" instead. You can use any [Map](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Map.html) implementation to do the same thing, of which the normal "default choice" is [HashMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html).